# Using Tidy on JSX produces incorrectly formatted code

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-snippets

I'm active in the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag and really like the ability to create runnable React snippets with the `Use BabelJS/ES2015` option.

However, when [tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidy) is run on a snippet containing JSX code it produces incorrectly-formatted output. Here's an example:

**Valid, un-formatted code**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
              <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Incorrectly-formatted, 'Tidy' code**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return ( <
      div >
      <
      h1 > Title < /h1> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < MyComponent / > , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Expected Result**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

When the `Use BabelJS/ES2015` option is selected, the JSX code should be interpreted as HTML and properly formatted. But as is [tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidy) cannot be used on snippets containing JSX.

Is there any plan to add support for JSX so it can be used with [tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidy)?

Comment: I mean I get that there are there are varying opinions on what constitutes "correct" formatting, but the current formatter is just plain wrong.