# Did I properly report this issue with a site? Is the lack of response normal?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

I've reported [an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348290/snippet-tidy-breaks-optional-chaining) in Snippet Tidy, and I haven't heard a response yet from anyone (other than a few comments from just curious people).  I'm wondering if there's somewhere else I should be reporting, or is this just the way issue reporting is on SO?

I ran into another issue with Tidy and found a Meta SO link that also appears to have had no response for a while now.

Not really to criticize, but kind of a little bit, I would find it a bit odd if this was the norm, as even your super busy Google tracker or your one-man OSS lib developer, even if it can't be resolved or it is low priority or even just plain wrong, will usually at least give some kind of feedback quickly (unless the project is inactive).

- *[Snippet Tidy breaks Optional Chaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348290/snippet-tidy-breaks-optional-chaining)*
- *[Using Tidy on JSX produces incorrectly formatted code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359358/using-tidy-on-jsx-produces-incorrectly-formatted-code)*

Comment: Yes this is the norm.

Comment: They usually don't say something until they actually *know* they're going to fix it, ignore it, or review it. This means that feature requests in particular can go a long time without a response from an employee. Bugs that legitimately break something get responses faster, though whether you get an initial "We see it and we're working on it" before a "This is fixed now" seems to depend on severity and how long it takes to fix it.

Comment: Just FYI, you posted that question on MSE, and now you are asking about that one on MSO.

Comment: @yivi Ah yes, I meant to put this on MSE.  I was reading the JSX issue and just happened to reach for the ask button here.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange and that was 5 years ago. I doubt there is much reason to expect it got any better, nor if that warrants removing the [status-declined]

Comment: @BSMP: Suggesting a new tag, `status-acknowledged` (*"read, registered in our parallel system, but not yet reviewed"*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not unusual.

However, there are changes in the process of how bugs are handled:

[What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/369403)

This means you can flag your post for moderator attention if someone has been able to reproduce the bug, and then they'll escalate it to the staff (and I have been able to reproduce it).

That is, if you count your post as *new*, which seems to sort-of apply as it was posted shortly before this change came to be.